# How can I have a cumulative translate within an SVG patternTransform?

Tags: svg

Consider the following SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="600" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="Pattern0" patternTransform="skewX(5)" x="0" y="0" width="0.1" height="0.042">
      <line x1="0" x2="1200" y1="0" y2="0" stroke-dasharray="25,25" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#Pattern0)" width="600" height="600" style="stroke:#0000FF;stroke-width:1" />
</svg>
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8RNCr/2/) to see it in action.

I'm trying to *stagger* the dashed lines in this pattern by some offset. The example above is a horizontal line, but the real lines may be rotated to any angle. The offset should be defined in the same units as the `dasharray`.

Adding a `patternTransform="translate(x)"` to the `pattern` doesn't work -- it just offsets the position of the *entire* repeated pattern instead of translating each repeated line in a cumulative fashion. Same goes for adding `transform="translate(x)"` to the `line`.

Adding a `patternTransform="skewX(x)"` works for horizontal lines and `patternTransform="skewY(x)"` works for vertical ones, but it doesn't work right at all for lines at other angles. Also, skewX/skewY require an *angle* as the argument, and I really need to move the lines based on the same units as the `dashArray`.

**EDIT:** Without boring anyone with the gory details, my ultimate goal is to translate AutoCAD hatch patterns into SVG files that I can use as background images in HTML. To see a little about how these patterns work, please see some of the examples here:

[AutoCAD 2010 User Documentation](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%202010%20User%20Documentation/index.html?url=WS73099cc142f4875513fb5cd10c4aa30d6b-7e57.htm,topicNumber=d0e368209) (Note the three links on the left -- overview, dashed lines, and multiple lines).

I would love to use an SVG pattern to do this, but it's looking more and more like I'll have to return to previous attempts of using a loop to create individual lines. I was trying to avoid this because frankly I've forgotten way too much high school trig and getting enough lines (at an arbitrary angles) to fill the canvas is eluding me.

Comment: Perhaps you could draw a picture of what you mean because "cumulative translate" isn't at all clear to me.

Comment: @RobertLongson, the second SVG in the linked Fiddle is sort of what I'm aiming for. However, since it relies on skewX, it only works properly for horizontal lines, and also is expressed in angles rather than the same units as the dashArray.

Comment: FWIW. That file's invalid as it has multiple identical id values. All cases display identically on Firefox which per spec is the right thing to do.

Comment: You don't just want patternTransform="rotate(30) skewX(25)" then?

Comment: I updated the fiddle for unique IDs, just dumb copypasta on my side for the sake of the example (I'm using Chrome). I definitely do not want to use "rotate(30) skewX(25)", it skews the *direction* of the lines rather than adjusting the offset of the dashes *along* the line. The fact that skewX() works for horizontal lines doesn't really help me, since I need to be able to offset the dash pattern of a line at *any* angle.

Comment: I'm afraid I still find it terribly unclear exactly what you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a short-cut way to create a staggered pattern.  You'll need to draw out a set of staggered lines yourself, up to the point where you can get the effect you want with a repeating (possibly skewed or rotated) rectangular grid.

To get the effect of two dashed lines, with the dashes offset to each other, your repeating tile needs to have two lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="600" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="Pattern0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
             x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="8.4%" 
             style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1;
                    stroke-dasharray:25,25; " >

      <line x1="0" x2="100%" y1="1%" y2="1%" />
      <line x1="0" x2="100%" y1="5.2%" y2="5.2%" 
            style="stroke-dashoffset:25" />

    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#Pattern0)" width="600" height="600" 
        style="stroke:#0000FF;stroke-width:1" />
</svg>
```

[image: Snapshot of the rendered SVG]

Explanation of the changes:

1. I've changed to `userSpaceOnUse` units to define the pattern tile.  This ensures that percentages defined when drawing the pattern are interpretted the same way as percentages drawn when defining the size of the tile.  (User space is default for `patternContentUnits`.)  The rectangle in your sample was the same size as the user space, so it wasn't making a difference, but it does if you change the size of the rectangle.

   If you really *wanted* the spacing of the lines to be proportional to the size of the rectangle being filled, this is a problem.  You could change both `patternUnits` and `patternContentUnits` to `objectBoundingBox` (the default for `patternUnits`), but then you have to define all your stroke properties relative to the rectangle size as well.
2. I've doubled the height of the tile, so that it is equivalent to two of your original tiles.  One tile now includes two horizontal lines.
3. I've offset the first line slightly so it doesn't get cut off by the edge of the tile (you were only getting a half-pixel stroke width displayed, and the difference becomes obvious if the second line isn't similarly clipped).
4. I've added the second line, with the dash pattern offset, at a vertical position that is half the tile height below the first line (1% + 8.4%/2 = 5.2%).

Like @Robert Longson, I'm not 100% certain I understand what you're asking, so if this isn't the effect you want please post a drawing of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @AmeliaBR. My ultimate goal is to replicate AutoCAD "*.PAT" hatch patterns using SVG. These define a series of repeating lines, each with an optional dash pattern, offset, and angle. I didn't want to bury the main issue in the minutia of dealing with this file format, which is why perhaps the reasons I'm trying to create patterns this way aren't obvious. I'm going to edit my question for clarity in case someone wants to dive into more details.